# How much time did medieval Christians devote to prayer?

Tags: catholicism, history, prayer, medieval-church, devotion

I was critiqued [on this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11675/christian-view-of-why-there-are-so-many-similarities-between-quran-and-bible) concerning it taking less time out of the day for someone to be a Muslim than a Christian, and that may be untrue for a majority of Christians today.

But how much time did an Christians between the 600's and the 1200's spend in prayer each day?  Were there novenas, rosaries, the divine office, the angelus, chaplets etc... back then and if so how did they come to be fairly ubiquitous?

How would anyone even begin to research what kinds of devotions one's own ancestors may have practiced?

Comment: The Angelus; a daily prayer at noon.  I'd need to research when that tradition began.

Answer (score 6):

Some [early forms of Rosary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_rosary#Key_dates) were known before 1200, although they were probably not as popular as from 13th century on. [Jesus prayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Prayer#Origins) popular in Orthodox church was definitely known. [Angelus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelus#History) is prayed outside monasteries since 13th century. [Way of the Cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stations_of_the_Cross#History) is even younger. Wikipedia article on [novena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novena#History) is a stub and brief search didn't find anything much better, but novenas could be known and prayed even in early Middle Ages.

We don't know very well how laymen prayed before 1200 - we can be sure they prayed, but most of the forms have not been recorded. I would guess that  devout Christians could pray a lot, but there was no prayer practice everyone (including the less devout) was supposed to join except for Holy Mass, which was not so common in some parts of Europe (in Western Europe there could be a net of churches, but in newly evangelized lands this was hardly the case).