# How did St John of Damascus view Islam?

Tags: church-history, islam, john-of-damascus

[John of Damascus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_of_Damascus) was one of the first Christian authors to write about the rise of Islam shortly after the time of Muhammad. I am fascinated by this man but I can't seem to find enough info about this subject on the Internet. I was wondering how exactly did he view Islam in his writings?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! Thanks for your fascinating question! FYI, there is some mention of John of Damascus and Islam in the answers to this question: "[Was Islam originally considered to be a Christian sect?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14630/was-islam-originally-considered-to-be-a-christian-sect/14642#14642)" Meanwhile, if you'd like to learn more about how this site ticks, feel free to browse some of the articles in the [Help Center](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: This was a good question. I'm glad you were helped, and this Q&A certainly helped a good number of other people too. If you'd like to know something else (about Matthew and Jews for example), please [ask a new question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Also, don't forget that you can mark Mike's answer as accepted (indicating you were satisfied with it) by clicking the check-mark under the down-arrow next to his answer.

Answer (score 10):

You may find a book that shows his writing about the followers of Islam [On Heresies (see 101) by St. John of Damascus](https://archive.org/stream/fathersofthechur009511mbp#page/n203/mode/2up) .

The writing of St. John of Damascus basically runs like this: (Actually he does not really say that much in depth, or from argumentation from scripture but still it is interesting)

1. He mentions Mohammed and his book
2. He pokes fun at the idea that a man can claim to receive such a book without any witnesses
3. The main heresy in Mohammed's book is that it denies Jesus to be God
4. He says Islamists accused the Christians at that time of idolatry because of how they venerated a cross and he in turn questions their veneration of the black stone at Mecca
5. He accused Mohammed of legalizing polygamy
6. He proceeds to make fun of some strange additional books written by Mohammed  especially the first about a Camel that went to heaven
7. He returns to the subject of their opposition to veneration of images, Saints , Mary, and rejection of Priesthoods.
8. Finally he states the traditional doctrine of the Trinity to rebuff their main error.

Comment: He basically viewed Islam as a Christian heresy.  There's also a nice excerpt from John's writings on the subject at: http://orthodoxinfo.com/general/stjohn_islam.aspx

Comment: What year was his book published?